# Why layout_height and width should be defined?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I don´t understand why when I add requestFocus on a TextView I need to define layout_height and layout_width, but without it I don´t.

This is my XML without the requestFocus.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRespiratory"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Respiratory Rate"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnRespiratory"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnRespiratory"/>
```

But, when I modify for adding the focus to the TextView, it's asking for layout_height and layout_width and crashing. This is the new code, with requestFocus.

```
 <TextView>
    android:id="@+id/txtRespiratory"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Respiratory Rate"      
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnRespiratory"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnRespiratory"
    <requestFocus/>
</TextView>
```

Can anyone explain to me why I have to set up height and width when the focus is requested?

Thanks!

Comment: you put `<requestFocus/>` in `TextView` before close the tag. actually it should be as a child tag in `TextView`, not as a field.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are using angular bracket(>) at another place. Try it with the following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRespiratory"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Respiratory Rate"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnRespiratory"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnRespiratory">
    <requestFocus/>
</TextView>
```

Comment: Compiler is not complaining, but unfourtunately the textview is not getting the focus...

Comment: What focus you're expecting in the textView, It'll just show your data. Focus can be used for editText have a cursor as the activity starts. Your question clear enough. Please explain your requirements.

Comment: I´ll reformulate the question.